# Linking 2 graph legends with echarts-for-react

Tags: reactjs, echarts, echarts-for-react

I'm trying out some things with echarts-for-react, and I have an interface that looks like this:
[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M5mS.png)

the two graphs have the same elements inside, tho they show 2 different values, but the legend is exactly the same.
What i would like to do would be to link the two legends, so that I could have only the one on the left and that would control both graphs, but I'm can't find out how to do it.

I tried to have them share for example an array, with the values of the legend inside but that didn't work, and I tried to do a single graph with a pie series and a bar series but that was getting too complicated, so I would like to know if there is a way to implement it using two different graphs, otherwise I'll try to go down that route again

Thanks for any insight you'll offer

Answer (score 1):

You can put both graphs into the same echarts object and if they share the [`name`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.name) property they will be linked in the legend.

[Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=dataset-link&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsA2BTA5l6AJgFzIC-ANGrAB4CC1EAziUmAJ4hYkDkAxgIZhcwAE5tuFKm3pMWk9DhERiyWGFA8ArJoCk3WPNiMsSrM1gBtKulTo7ajl1jcARvxHdK99NH4BbJ25-T2s7AkF-EgsLAAZyWABGAGYADgBdNNDDG1D0dk4eNw8vb18AwpDvWHCwSMtY-ISYgCYMrJKcqvzAosrS_0DePvsauui42BSktvts5FyHAucQCCxhuxF-AggAV3NuJJi9DrtefCERKO5NI89nZt1uNJP0UaiFmzLA4PiAN34MDsnAAWTRzexIL4VP4AoEkABsAHZwXZIQMeEMYYCnElgaQPrBMrMqJlSEA) is a small example:

```js
option = {
  legend: {},
  xAxis: {type: 'category'},
  yAxis: {},
  grid: { top: '55%' },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'bar',
      name: 'a',
      data: [[0, 138]]
    },
    {
      type: 'bar',
      name: 'b',
      data: [[0, 102]]
    },
    {
      type: 'bar',
      name: 'c',
      data: [[0, 83]]
    },
    {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '30%',
      center: ['50%', '25%'],
      data: [
        {name: 'a', value: 45},
        {name: 'b', value: 67},
        {name: 'c', value: 34}
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There is also an [offical example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=dataset-link) making use of `dataset` which might be interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly.
Just a minor issue, any way that i can have the bar series and the pie series have matching colours? Cause now it's a bit weird, i have for example a red pie slice, and when i turn it off it works on both the pie and the bar, but that bar had a different colour ( tho the datas removed are correct)

Comment: I would need to see your code to be sure whats causing it, but as long as you specify the data items in the same order or use a [dataset](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Dataset) the colors should match. You can also set the [color](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.data.itemStyle.color) of each data item individually.